# Error sometimes happens in calling kubernetes api

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Recently, I need to call k8s api(http://x.x.x.x:8001/api/v1/namespaces/pods) to create docker container, k8s's api will raise error message and part of container will start failed when I call api in parallel, for example, create 8 or more containers at the same time.[image]
Anyone can help ?

Comment: The exitCode:1 possibly means the container exited with an error. Can you check the logs of the container?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error message from the Kubernetes API. It just provides the status of your pod's containers and this container's main processes has been terminated with exit code 1.

You can check the failed container's logs via `kubectl log $PODNAME -c $CONTAINERNAME`.

Comment: I don't use controller like rc, deployment, call pod create api directly, seems could find container with command "docker ps -a"

Comment: I'm aware you don't create any controllers but that wasn't the point of my post. The application IN YOUR POD is crashing and this is not a Kubernetes error.